# CircleProgress обратного отсчета

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdowntimer

Не могу понять, как изменить данный таймер под убывание, т.е с 20 до 0(к примеру). Просто не понял как stroke-dashoffset подогнать под убывание. Я сделал обычный radial timer с использованием svg.

Может есть альтернативные решения моей проблемы? Или есть уже готовые плагины для таких дейтсвий?

http://jsfiddle.net/89p76a5z/2/

P.S. Не ругайтесь за вары ;)

```js
var time = 20;
var initialOffset = '440';
var i = 20;

$('.circle_animation').css('stroke-dashoffset', 0);

$(".pause").click(function(){
   clearInterval(interval);
});

$(".resume").click(function(){
   
interval = setInterval(function() {
    $('h2').text(i);
    $('.circle_animation').css('stroke-dashoffset', initialOffset-((i+1)*(initialOffset/time)));
    i++;  
}, 1000);
});
```

```css
.item {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.item h2 {
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 125px;
    width: 100%;
}

svg {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.circle_animation {
  stroke-dasharray: 440; /* this value is the pixel circumference of the circle */
  stroke-dashoffset: 440;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="item">
  <h2>0</h2>
  <svg width="160" height="160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle id="circle" class="circle_animation" r="69.85699" cy="81" cx="81" stroke-width="20" stroke="#6fdb6f" fill="none"/>
  </svg>
</div>
<button class="pause">pause</button>
<button class="resume">resume</button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
var time = 20;
var initialOffset = '440';
var i = 20;

$('.circle_animation').css('stroke-dashoffset', 0);

$(".pause").click(function() {
  clearInterval(interval);
});

$(".resume").click(function() {

  interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (i == 0) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      i = 20;
    }
    $('h2').text(i);
    $('.circle_animation').css('stroke-dashoffset', initialOffset - ((i - 1) * (initialOffset / time)));
    i--;
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.item {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.item h2 {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 125px;
  width: 100%;
}

svg {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.circle_animation {
  stroke-dasharray: 440;
  /* this value is the pixel circumference of the circle */
  stroke-dashoffset: 440;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="item">
  <h2>0</h2>
  <svg width="160" height="160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle id="circle" class="circle_animation" r="69.85699" cy="81" cx="81" stroke-width="20" stroke="#6fdb6f" fill="none"/>
  </svg>
</div>
<button class="pause">pause</button>
<button class="resume">resume</button>
```